# Create col1, col2, col3 using MVC where (1,2,3 are dynamically generated)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

- 1> .cs page

```
public partial class TBL_FG_MENUS
{
     public string ColName1{ get; set; }
     public string ColName2{ get; set; }....ntimes

     public string ColValue1{ get; set; }
     public string ColValue2{ get; set; }....ntimes
}
```

Question:

1. I need to loop inside view using this model

   2> .cshtml page (view)

```
 @{
     int i=1;
     foreach(var item in Model)
     {
         <p>@item.ColName+i<p><br/>
         i++;
     }

     i=1;
     foreach(var item in Model)
     {
         <p>@item.ColValue+i<p><br/>
         i++;
     }

 }
```

Here I want `ColName1`, `ColValue1` n times inside the loop

Comment: Have you considered using collections or arrays? They kind of allow you to iterate over the elements.

Comment: Come on.. how collections fit here.?? i have property's inside class i have assigned them some values inside controller... i just want that column embedded with integer part in such a way that it read like a property as set inside class to get its set value from model...

Comment: Instead of using multiple properties as you currently do, you could have one collection property in your model. Then you can easily loop through the values of this collection in your view in order to display them.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to adapt your view model a little bit so that it uses 2 collections:

```
public partial class TBL_FG_MENUS
{
     public IList<string> ColNames { get; set; }
     public IList<string> ColValues { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@foreach(var name in Model.ColNames)
{
    <p>@name</p><br/>
}

 @foreach(var value in Model.ColValues)
 {
     <p>@value</p><br/>
 }
```

If for some reason you cannot use collections, then the only way to achieve that is by using reflection:

```
@foreach(var prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("ColName")))
{
    <p>@Html.Display(prop.Name)</p><br/>
}

@foreach(var prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("ColValue")))
{
    <p>@Html.Display(prop.Name)</p><br/>
}
```

Obviously you should bear in mind that using reflection could have negative impact on the performance of your application and you might want to consider caching the property names used in the `foreach` loops to avoid querying them every time.

Comment: Hey Darin! 
need help once again,

now the list of column values are not coming in order they should be.. I mean they following certain pattern...
Ex: colval1 , colval2, colval3 \n
      colval3, colval2, colval1 \n
     colval1, colval2, colval3... any clue why is is unordered????